# Comparing unsigned and signed int

Tags: c, casting

I guess this is one of the classical questions.

As far as I know comparing `unsigned` and `signed` int are performed using unsigned arithmetic, which means that if `length = -1 = unsigned max of 32 bits`.

> The code can be fixed by either declaring length to be an int, or by changing the test of the for loop to be i < length.

Declaring length to be an int, it's easy to understand, but changing the `loop to be i < length` not really easy.

If we have the following situation: `5 < -1` which if performed using unsigned arithmetic, in my computer yields `5 < 4294967295`, how can this be a solution, it seems like it will access undefined elements.

**Code**

```
float sum_elements(float a[], unsigned length)
{
    int i;
    float result = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= length-1; i++)
        result += a[i];

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why would you even write your loop end condition as `i <= len - 1` anyway, that's really odd

Comment: The point is that `length` is greater than or equal to 0 (it is `unsigned` after all). So the comparison with `i < length` will always work, even when `length` is 0.  But the comparison `i <= length-1` won't work when `length` is 0, because `length - 1` will wrap to some very large number when `length` is 0.

Comment: Can't you change "i" to "unsigned"?

Comment: @harold the example was from a book, I didn't understand the part of: `...changing the test of the for loop to be i < length - will fix the problem`.

Comment: @dud3 what didn't you understand about that, what the fix is or why it works?

Comment: @harold Now that I see it's actually `(i < length)` I was still thinking of `(i < length - 1)`, which if we'd give `length = 0` it would be a problem, but in this case we'd have a problem only if `length = -1`. Sorry, can't believe I didn't notice it before.

Comment: @harold it was why it does `(i < length)` work, but obviously it does if `length = 0`, like I said somehow I ended up seeing it as `(i < length - 1)`, I guess because of the original problem. ;(

Answer (score 1):

Consider the condition.

i <= length-1

As you mentioned, if length is zero then you will enter into a situation like 5 < 4294967295.

Changing the condition to "i < length" will prevent this.

Also changing type of variable "i" to "unsigned" makes sense because (a) it is array index.  (b) you are comparing it with an "unsigned".

So I would prefer this code.

```
float sum_elements(float a[], unsigned length)
{
    unsigned   i = 0;
    //float result = 0.0; //Refer comment section.
    double result = 0.0;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        result += (double)a[i];

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Probably even better with `double result`.

Comment: @chqrlie, yeah. But I am not sure if I have to typecast a[i] to double while adding.

Comment: the conversion is performed automatically by the compiler. Some compilers might issue a diagnostic for such implicit conversions, in which case a cast could silence such warnings.

Answer (score 0):

A pedantic `<=` compare of and `int <= unsigned` would test for negative-ness first.

```
for (i = 0; i < 0 || ((unsigned) i) <= length-1; i++)
```

Removing the -1 helps to avoid overflow.

```
for (i = 0; i < 0 || ((unsigned) i) < length; i++)
```

A good compiler will likely optimize the code so 2 compares are not actually in the executable.

If `-Wsign-conversion` or its equivalent compiler option is not used, drop the cast for cleaner code [@R..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553021/comparing-unsigned-and-signed-int/40553096?noredirect=1#comment68344649_40553096)

```
for (i = 0; i < 0 || i < length; i++)
```

---

As well commented by [@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553021/comparing-unsigned-and-signed-int/40553096?noredirect=1#40553021) the compare may perform well but subsequent operations on `i` may be a problem.  In particular when `i == INT_MAX`, the `i++` is UB.

Better to use `size_t` (an unsigned type) for array size computation and indexing.

```
float sum_elements(float a[], size_t length) {
    float result = 0;
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        result += a[i];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Remove the cast. It's not needed and very ugly. If a compiler produces a signedness-mismatched-comparison warning, its range analysis needs fixing and you should file a bug report; it can readily see that the promotion cannot change the value.

Comment: This solution is not correct: if `length > INT_MAX`, the code invokes undefined behavior. It is much better to change the type of `i` to be `unsigned`.

Comment: @R.. The `(unsigned)`  is certainly optional.  It is included here to quiet the warning `warning: conversion to 'unsigned int' from 'int' may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]` .  It usefulnesses shows the intentional action by the coder of the the type change.  The cast is required by certain coding standards.

Comment: @chqrlie  Given `unsigned length`, `length > INT_MAX` does _not_ invoke UB.  This code does cast `i` to `unsigned` so I am unclear on the rest of your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553021/comparing-unsigned-and-signed-int/40553096?noredirect=1#comment68344742_40553096).

Comment: @chux: if `length` is greater than `INT_MAX`, which is perfectly legal and possible on current 64-bit systems, `i++` will cause arithmetic overflow when `i` reaches `INT_MAX`.  Your approach with a cast to `(unsigned)`, with or without the `i < 0` test just hides the problem that the compiler correctly diagnoses with `-Wextra`.

Comment: @chqrlie Agree that `i++` results in UB when `i == INT_MAX`.  My focus was on the `int/unsigned` compare issue, but the higher level problem you identified is true.  An `int i` may not be of sufficient range for `unsigned length`.

Answer (score 0):

Option #1:

```
for (i = 0; i <= (int)length-1; i++)
```

Option #2:

```
for (i = 0; i+1 <= length; i++)
```

Option #3:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your compilator job's, when he creates he's parser lexer, he uses a table for your variables. If he saw something like :

```
float a = b + 60
```

60 will be cast in 60.0 by your compilator.
I think this is the same thing here:

```
(unsigned int)length = (unsigned int)length (int)-1
```

becomes:

```
(unsigned int)length = (int)length (int)-1;
```

If you want a proper arithmetic comparison, you should use the flag -Wextra

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not perform as expected in 2 cases:

- if `length == 0`, `length - 1`, computed using unsigned arithmetic, is a very large number and comparing `i <= length - 1` will be always true because the comparison is also performed using unsigned arithmetics.
- if `length` is larger than the maximum integer value, `i` can never reach such a value and although the comparison performed using unsigned arithmetic will work as expected, the indexing `a[i]` will be incorrect on 64-bit systems where the negative index will point outside the array.

The compiler correctly diagnoses a real problem.  Using a signed type for `i` and comparing that to an unsigned `length` expression can lead to unexpected behavior.  Correct the problem this way:

```
float sum_elements(float a[], unsigned length) {
    double result = 0.0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result += a[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Notes:

- the types for `length` and `i` really should be `size_t` as this may be a larger type than `unsigned`.
- the sum should be computed using `double` arithmetics, to achieve better precision than using `float`.  Precision will be better, but still limited.  Summing the array elements in a different order can produce a different result.

Answer (score 0):

Lose the `i` variable, to save a little stack space and make the function faster.

```
float sum_elements(float a[], unsigned length)
{
    float result = 0;

    while (length--)
        result += *a++;

    return result;
}
```